# How to make volume appear on Desktop with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos

Note: This is not about how to make a folder or a symbolic link/alias to a volume using Objective C.

I'm attempting to make a program that works similarly to how Mac OS creates a Finder sidebar and Desktop link to a volume when a external volume is mounted, but works for NTFS. Currently, to mount an NTFS volume as read-write in Mac OS, you have to declare the volume as `rw,nobrowse` when mounting; `rw` is for read-write, and `nobrowse` is for declaring the volume as private and not to hook into the various GUI functions that occur when a volume is mounted. It is not possible (without altering the kext or `mount_ntfs`) to mount the volume without declaring `nobrowse`.

Unfortunately, `nobrowse` marks the volumes as private and they don't show up in the Finder sidebar and on the Desktop by default when mounted. I would like to be able to replicate the functionality of a non-`nobrowse` volume for a `rw,nobrowse` mounted NTFS volume. I know I can create a symbolic link on the Desktop, but this isn't the same thing.

Is it possible to use Objective C and hook into Finder or some system level API like `CoreFoundation` to make it show the volume on the Desktop, or mark the volume as non-private after being mounted? I assume no for the second one, since this is a kernel level/kext thing, but not sure about the first.

Comment: you can look into disk arbitrator

Comment: I know that's how I can hook into the events that happen, but I didn't see anything in Disk Arbitrator about how to show a volume on the Desktop.